# How can I get my logo sticky in a div while using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

I'm trying to get my logo stick to the top of the page but I can't manage to do that.
I've tried with:

```
#logo {
position: sticky; 
top:0
}
```

I also check if there's an overflow property but I've found nothing, I'm also using bootstrap framework version 5.

This is the part where I've put logo:

```
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 align-items-start d-flex">
            <img src="../media/logos/mb-logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-7 col-md-8 align-items-end justify-content-end d-flex" id="menu_mobile">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                    <span class="menu_item">about me</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                    <span class="menu_item">competencies</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                    <span class="menu_item">portfolio</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                    <span class="menu_item">contact</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col justify-content-end align-items-center d-flex" id="menu_desk">
            <span class="menu_item_desk">about me</span>
            <span class="menu_item_desk">competencies</span>
            <span class="menu_item_desk">portfolio</span>
            <span class="menu_item_desk">contact</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

edit: after trying the solution posted by @Fork:

```
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 align-items-start d-flex " >
            <img src="../media/logos/mb-logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid position-fixed top-0" alt="logo">
        </div>
```

The logo stay in position while I scroll down but other element changed of disposition. I managed to fix them adding some paddings and margin

edit 2: Here's the snippet and thanks to Fork now it works fine, another thing I would like to accomplish is that when the page is scrolled, the image goes up above the page for a tiny bit. I found this fiddle but is not exactly what i mean https://jsfiddle.net/z2r40y8c/. The image needs to go up and block at a specified amount of pixels.

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

body{
    background-color: #161616;
}
#logo {
 margin-left: 25px !important;
 position: fixed;
 top:0
}
.menu_mobile{
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.menu_item {
    font-family: 'sublimaextrabold';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(112,112,112,1);
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 810px) {

#menu_mobile {
    display: none !important;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {

    #menu_desk {
        display: none !important;
    }
    
    }
.menu_item_desk {
    font-family: 'sublimaextrabold';
    color: rgba(112,112,112,1);
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1197px) {
    .menu_item_desk {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 993px) {
    .menu_item_desk {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MB</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../html/style.css">
</head>

<body ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">

<div class="container" id="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 align-items-start d-flex">
                        <img src="https://www.startpage.com/av/proxy-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Ffr%2Fimages%2Fthumb%2Foblong_noun_002_25303.jpg%3Fversion%3D5.0.245&sp=1657096049T030f5c6f84a41f399845576d2d63d9849144e614f9e0077172506ae40946828e" id="logo" class="img-fluid position-fixed top-0" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center " id="menu_desk">
                        <span class="menu_item_desk">section 1</span>
                        <span class="menu_item_desk">section 2</span>
                        <span class="menu_item_desk">section 3</span>
                        <span class="menu_item_desk">section 4</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-11 align-items-end pt-3 justify-content-end d-flex" id="menu_mobile">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                                <span class="menu_item">section 1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                                <span class="menu_item">section 2</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                                <span class="menu_item">section 3</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex">
                                <span class="menu_item">section 4</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you just want the `position: sticky;` just on the logo rather than the whole navigation bar, but if you want to go that route, I would suggest using `position: fixed;` instead. Additionally, apply it to the `div` that's surrounding your image. Like so:

```
<div class="col-4 col-md-3 align-items-start d-flex position-fixed top-0">
 <img src="../media/logos/mb-logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank for the reply :), I tried changing position to fixed in the css and applying it to the div. this makes the logo to stick at the top :) but for some reason it changes the disposition of other elements

Comment: Would you mind updating your post with a snippet so I can see it?

Comment: you mean like that?

Comment: Not exactly. On your post, click on edit, and in the toolbar of your body, there is a feature called `JavaScript\HTML\CSS snippet`. Alternatively you can use `CTRL+M` shortcut. In there add your HTML and CSS which you require, run it to test it out and then insert it into your post. We'll be able to see a snippet/view of your Navigation bar. You can read more about it here: [Runnable Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Oh understood, but unfortunately I'm working locally for now so you won't be able to see the logo and the correct font. If there's another way I would do that.

Comment: It's fine, you could add an alt text to it, or if possible you can host your logo somewhere and copy the link address into the `src` of your image. Alternatively you could also google a logo you would like to use as placeholder and use the same concept

Comment: Ok I've put a rectangle that is basically the shape of the logo, hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the problem is, that for some constructions, like a bootstrap carousel, if you want to display it on a fullscreen, bootstrap requires the height of html to be set to 100%.
For position: sticky it is required to have no height set.
You could try making the nav sticky with JS:

```
    const nav = document.querySelector('#nav');
let navTop = nav.offsetTop;

function fixedNav() {
  if (window.scrollY >= navTop) {    
    nav.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove('fixed');    
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixedNav);
```

and the CSS for the activated navbar:

```
#nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#nav.fixed ul li img {
  height: 36px;
}
#nav.fixed ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```